# How can you query for "min(arr)>10" in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.inventory.insertMany([
   { item: "journal", qty: 25, tags: ["blank", "red"], dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
   { item: "notebook", qty: 50, tags: ["red", "blank"], dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
   { item: "paper", qty: 100, tags: ["red", "blank", "plain"], dim_cm: [ 14, 21 ] },
   { item: "planner", qty: 75, tags: ["blank", "red"], dim_cm: [ 22.85, 30 ] },
   { item: "postcard", qty: 45, tags: ["blue"], dim_cm: [ 10, 15.25 ] }
]);
```

return document that min(dim_cm)>15

it seems `db.inventory.find( { dim_cm: { $all: {$gt:15} } } )` is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you should work with `$not` and `$lte` operators to find the document with `dim_cm` contains all elements greater than 15.

```
db.collection.find({
  dim_cm: {
    $not: {
      $lte: 15
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KHWqGVbsEXc)

Reference: [Single Query Condition](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition)

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive syntax would be chaining up `$min` and `$gt` in an `$expr`

```
db.inventory.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        $min: "$dim_cm"
      },
      15
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2zFqepzkzNX)